# Why am I not getting any data back when I click on ImageButton in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have the following Gridview, with an ImageButton in the last column. I am trying to return the First and Last names from the row from which the button has been clicked. I have spent several hours looking on here and other sites trying to get it to work, but with no success.

If someone could have a look at my code and see if I am doing anything wrong it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**ASP Code**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvSecondaryContacts" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ContactID" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="gvSecondaryContacts_OnRowCommand"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactID" HeaderText="ContactID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ContactID" Visible="false"/>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSecFirstName" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSecLastName" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSecEmail" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Position">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClubPosition") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSecClubPosition" Text='<%# Eval("ClubPosition") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>                   
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibtnDelete" CommandName="Delete" AlternateText="Delete Contact" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>
```

**VB Code**

```
Public Sub gvSecondaryContacts_OnRowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Delete" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim row = gvSecondaryContacts.Rows(index)
        Dim ContactID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gvSecondaryContacts.DataKeys(index).Value)
        Dim sFirstName As String = gvSecondaryContacts.Rows(index).Cells(1).Text
        Dim sLastName As String = gvSecondaryContacts.Rows(index).Cells(2).Text
        MsgBox("Your name is " & sFirstName & " " & sLastName)
    End If

End Sub
```

I have also tried the following for the ImageButton but it returned **is a type and cannot be used as an expression** error

```
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>                   
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibtnDelete" CommandName="Delete" AlternateText="Delete Contact" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container, GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Can you show where you data bind the grid?

Comment: If you are not binding the grid in post back then the rows collection is probably empty.

Comment: @Kaf The grid is databound in the page load in the post back. There are 2 records showing in the grid, but it is returning an index of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hanlde the click-event instead. You can cast the `ImageButon's` [**NamingContainer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) to `GridViewRow` in the click-event handler. Then you just have to use `FindControl`:

```
Protected Sub Delete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctrl = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    Dim row = DirectCast(ctrl.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    ' you should rename this to LblFirstName
    Dim Label2 = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label2"), Label)
    ' you should rename this to LblLastName
    Dim Label1 = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
    'MessageBoxes in ASP.NET don't make much sense
    MsgBox("Your name is " & Label2.Text & " " & Label1.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim after a little tweak that is now working. Just had to change Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button) to Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, ImageButton) and it returned what I was after.

Comment: @Clanger67: Sorry, i was fairly sure that `ImageButton` inherits from `Button` (what's not true). Edited my answer accordingly. Since we only need it for the namingcontainer property i've casted it to `Control` now (I prefer to cast only to what i need).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Dim sFirstName As String = ((Label)gvSecondaryContacts.Rows(index).Cells(1).FindControl("Label2")).Text
    Dim sLastName As String =((Label)gvSecondaryContacts.Rows(index).Cells(2).FindControl("Label1")).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is setting `CommandArgument of ImageButton`

```
CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container, GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"
```

You don't have do it according to this [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). Also you (*if data binding done from server side*) should bind your gridview only if page is not posting back as;

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
   'Bind your gridview here
End if
```